# What happens when you cast Mirror Image while mounted?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, mount

If you are mounted when you cast mirror image, do the images also have mirror copies of your horse, or would their be 5 images sitting in the air around you?

Comment: I've removed the positioning question - that's unrelated to the mounted casting issue, and should be asked separately in its own question. You can still retrieve its content in your [revision history](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/72660/revisions), which you can access by clicking the 'edited X time ago' link at the bottom center of your post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exactly what it says: it is a personal spell that creates images of **you**.

As such, the spell is trivially defeated by saying "I attack the image *on the horse*"

If the horse is your familiar (or similar) then the spell can also affect it.

Comment: Well done spotting the Familar exception!

Comment: Does it make any difference that "For simplicity, assume that you share your mount’s space during combat" (*PH* 157)?